# Exchange - Programmatically Created Mailbox Can't Access Users' Calendars

Tags: vb.net, powershell, exchange-server

I've been using a web application I've written to remotely create users/mailboxes on my Exchange server.  However, users created using this method have been unable to see other users' calendar information within the same organization.  Did I forget some important parameter?

I'm almost certainly not following best practices, but I essentially craft a command and send that to the Exchange powershell for my organization, like so:

```
Dim runspace As Runspace
runspace = ConnectToExchange()

Dim command = New Command("New-Mailbox")
command.Parameters.Add("Name", firstName & " " & lastName)
command.Parameters.Add("Alias", userName)
command.Parameters.Add("OrganizationalUnit", ou)
command.Parameters.Add("UserPrincipalName", userName & "@" & domainName)
command.Parameters.Add("SamAccountName", userName)
command.Parameters.Add("FirstName", firstName)
command.Parameters.Add("Initials", "")
command.Parameters.Add("LastName", lastName)
command.Parameters.Add("Password", securePassword)
command.Parameters.Add("ResetPasswordOnNextLogon", True)
command.Parameters.Add("Database", db)
command.Parameters.Add("AddressBookPolicy", abp)

runspace.Open()
Dim pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline()
pipeline.Commands.Add(command)

' Execute the command
Dim results = pipeline.Invoke()

runspace.Dispose()
```

I should mention that I've reviewed the [docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997663%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx), but the only thing that stands out to me is the Sharing Policy parameter.  Reviewing now..

EDIT:  I have the same Sharing Policy applied as a test user I've just created.  I can view others calendars, but the test user cannot.

SECOND EDIT:  I ran the following cmdlets for both my normal account (which can see calendars) and the test account (which cannot see calendars):

```
Get-Mailbox identity.here | Format-List * | Out-File C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\file.txt
```

I then ran these through a diff tool and found the differences.  There was nothing notable that would cause this issue! I don't know where to turn to next.

Answer (score 1):

please run the following CMDlet on both accounts:

```
Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity john@contoso.com:\Calendar
```

Please note that the "Calendar" part seems to depend on your Exchange installation language (in German its "Kalender" for example).

If i get you right your account probably has AccessRights:{PublishingEditor} set.
If so run the following CMDlet on the account that doesnt have access:

```
Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity john@contoso.com:\Calendar -User Default -AccessRights Reviewer
```

Hope that helps

Paul

Comment: Thanks for your help Paul.  Unfortunately, both the unaffected and affected accounts `AccessRights` are set to `<AvailabilityOnly>`

Comment: ok, what outlook and Exchange Version are you using? and can your test user see the calendars but cant access them or do they not show up at all?

Comment: I am using Outlook 2013, as are a couple of the affected users, but I believe it's a server side issue rather than client-side.  Just a hunch, as I am able to see calendars using another account using the same client (2013).  I think the majority of affected users are on 2010.  The issue is that, with the test user account, the Scheduling Assistant only shows "free/busy information could not be retrieved" with greyed out lines where calendar events would be shown.  Additionally, these affected users are unable to set Out of Office - "it says that it cannot connect to the server".